# Adding serial no in crystal report cross tab report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crosstab

How to add serial number in a crystal report cross tab report? I am using dataset as a datasource.

Comment: Can you give us more details - eg. the query you are using, the fields currently included in the crosstab and where you want to see the serial number in the crosstab?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing unique about a serial number field, it's just a string. Just add it to the crosstab.